# Regex to disallow plus sign and underscores

Tags: c#, regex, c#-4.0

so I have a regex currently which looks like this:

```
   string username = Regex.Replace(competitor, @"(\s+|@|&|'|\(|\)|<|>|#)", "");
```

What this does is removes @, &, ', (, ), <, or > and replaces them with  "" (empty string)

Now I'd like to add to this regex the following criteria as well:

- remove any part of string that can contains these: .com, .net, .org, .edu
- remove + sign from string, wherever it may be found in string
- remove Consecutive underscores __
- remove An underscore _, hyphen -, or period . at the beginning of a username (for example, -pezcollector

Can someone help me out with this? I've never quite understood regex expressions...

How can this be added?

Comment: What do you mean by "remove + sign from string, wherever it it begins"? An example maybe? Also by remove consecutive underscores do you mean "___" => "" or "___" => "_"?

Comment: @V0ldek for example: +myname+ output is: myname  then:  +_myname+ , output is myname , ++myname++_    output is: myname  or _my+name_   then the output again is: myname

Comment: So you want to remove all + or _ signs from the beginning or end of the string?

Comment: @V0ldek Yes that's it ^^ and consecutive underscores __ as well ... For + sign anywhere in string, for single underscore just from beginning, and for consecutive underscore __ anywhere from the string

Comment: I can see my first comment was malformed because of Markdown, so I'll try again, by removing underscores you mean
user\_\_\_name => user\_name
or
user\_\_\_name => username

Comment: @V0ldek okay let see examples:

1. _username => _username    only if the underscore is at the beginning, then it is okay
2. user_name => username
3. user__name => username
4. +_user__name => _username
5. +_u+_sername => _username

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177623/discussion-between-user987-and-v0ldek).

Comment: this can manage your 2nd, 3rd and 4th condition `string output = Regex.Replace(competitor, @"[^0-9a-zA-Z]+", "");` removing all your special characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So step by step

> remove any part of string that contains these: .com, .net, .org, .edu

```
Regex.Replace(competitor, @"(.com|.net|.org|.edu)", "");
```

> remove + sign from string, wherever it may be found in string

```
Regex.Replace(competitor, @"\+", "");
```

> remove consecutive underscores __

```
Regex.Replace(comptetitor, @"(__+)", "")
```

> remove an underscore _, hyphen -, or period . at the beginning of a username

```
Regex.Replace(competitor, @"^(_|\.|-)+", "");
```

You can combine the plus sign removal with your existing regexp into:

```
Regex.Replace(competitor, @"(\s+|@|&|'|\(|\)|<|>|#|\+)", "");
```

You'll have to run the last two replaces separately, as removing other characters can result in `_` `-` or `.` moving to the beginning of the name, or underscores "sticking" together; for example `.#..usern_#_ame` would get converted into `..usern__ame` if you just run the `^(_|\.|-)+` and `(__+)` clauses with everything else.
Also I suggest you that run the first regexp separately, since you said that `.comuser` turns into `user`, so you need to run the first replacement before removing the starting period.

There's a problem with that, however. You can supply a username that looks like this:
`user.co.comm`. Then, after running one `Regex.Replace` you'll get `user.com`. I don't know if there's a standard method in .NET that would help you out with this, and doing such a "reactive" replacement in one sweep would require a more sophisticated algorithm. 
For a simple solution, however, you can just run the first replace for as long as there are any matches. It'll take pessimistic time of `O(n^2)`, where `n` is the length of the username, which would happen if the entire username looked for example like this: `.co.co.co.co.co.commmmmm`.

So finally you'd want something like:

```
var username = Regex.Replace(competitor, @"(\s+|@|&|'|\(|\)|<|>|#|\+)", "");
username = Regex.Replace(username, @"(__+)", "");
username = Regex.Replace(username, @"^(_|\.|-)+", "");

// remove .com/.net etc. here, for example using while(Match) Replace
```

As usual with regexps, you need to test this extensively, and please, let me know if I overlooked something.

EDIT:

If you want a solution that works in amortized `O(n)` then it's also quite simple, you need to write your own "replace with empty" method, that after each match will go back exactly as many characters as it removed. I'm not gonna prove the complexity or correctness, but it's quite easy and optimal :)

Comment: Yay ty ty V0ldek ! I shall test this :) :)

Comment: _++__azar.il_ => returns _++__azar.il_  :(

Comment: If you want to use underscores in your example you need to escape them with a backslash \ or put them within the code-mode apostrophes \` \`

Comment: yes it works like  a charm, just tested all examples it's flawless ! =D

Comment: I also added an edit with the outline of an optimal solution.